# Typescript How to write an object type from two objects, so the two merged together will match the merged object type?

Tags: typescript

I'm trying to write a function that accepts a function, and variables that will be passed to the function to fetch more objects for pagination. Meaning that the function's argument must accept `skip`, and `limit`, but can accept additional variables as well.

See the code to see what I mean:

```
type PaginationVariables = {
    skip: number;
    limit: number;
};

type Props<T, EV, V extends EV & PaginationVariables> = {
    extraVariables: EV;
    fetchMore: (variables: V) => Promise<T[]>;
}

function fn<T, EV, V extends EV & PaginationVariables>({ extraVariables, fetchMore }: Props<T, EV, V>) {
    const skip = 0;
    const limit = 20
    const handleClick = () => {
        fetchMore({ skip, limit, ...extraVariables }).then(() => {})
    }
}
```

But it throws:

```
Argument of type '{ skip: number; limit: number; } & EV' is not assignable to parameter of type 'V'.
  '{ skip: number; limit: number; } & EV' is assignable to the constraint of type 'V', but 'V' could be instantiated with a different subtype of constraint 'PaginationVariables'.
```

I've met with this error before, but I don't know what I'm doing wrong now.

See [playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgcwJYDs7CQexQNTgJyTgCMAbCAZygF4oBvAKCmagoGskwAuKFAVwC2xCPgDcTFqSQCkwHvyEjxAX3ENQkWPkxgKAHgAqAGigBRHCZxQIAD2AQUAEyrmoAMliJU6LLgJEySgA%20GnoJZltgfDg8QhJyCh5zcRYoADMIYABjAAsAWUx8CB4ACgA3f3jKHhwAShoQmG0ZCghDAG0AXSCVBgY0vhQsjGx0lEMTc0trOwdnMysPeGQ0Eb84wIogkroZqJjKzZMM7PzC6GUeJp19YwXLIPrGVKzsCmBWDjBQgAYUlleKHeUCkMg%20tAATD9wlBAcCcnAnOQAMJSLJsUIlerUELPVIsE65ApFHafTgmUGyEwAOlpkWisQCCSgylq1OAOQcJSxDXorJhygYyiAA)

Comment: [Like this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBACghgcwJYDs7CQexQNTgJyTgCMAbCAZygF4oBvAKCmagoGskwAuKFAVwC2xCPgDcTFqSQCkwHvyEjxAX3ENQkWPkxgKAHgAqAGigBRHAD4a9CcwgAPYPjh5CJchR7nxLKADMIYABjAAsAWUx8CB49HCgHYAgUABMqcygAMlhEVHQsXAIiMkoLAAoAN0L3Sh4cAEoaKxhtGQoIQwBtAF0LFQYGPz4UIIxsfxRDE3MyunjHZ1cijxMA4PDI6GUeZp19YzNLBsZfIOwKYFYOMGsABh8WU5RzqCkZC9oAJhvbKEfnkLgKXIAGEpEE2NZSg1qFZjr4WKtQhEoqVZuxOCZXrITAA6PEJBZVYpUZR1HHAEJJUpQxr0Uk-ZQMZRAA)? My rule of thumb is to always move the generic as close to its usage as possible. As such, it's redundant on the containing type and can be moved closer.

Comment: I don't understand the purpose of `V`; if you remove it [then things compile fine](https://tsplay.dev/mbALoN).  Can you demonstrate a need for `V` to be potentially narrower than `EV & PaginationVariables`?

Comment: Both of those work, `V` was before `EV`, before `V` was extending `PaginationVariables`, and it didn't work, so started to try out things, and then added `EV`. Still not sure though why it doesn't work, but it doesn't really matter as I got the solution now, thanks.

Comment: So, do you want to see my approach written up as an answer? I can explain why your current version doesn't work if I do.

Comment: I want to, of course.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a [generic function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/generics.html), the *caller* gets to specify the type parameters.  So in your version of `fn()`, nothing stops a caller from doing something like this:

```
fn({
  extraVariables: { a: "hello" },
  fetchMore(variables: { a: string, skip: number, limit: number, somethingElse: number[] }) {
    return Promise.resolve(variables.somethingElse.map(x => String(x)));
  }
});

/* fn<
     string, 
     { a: string; }, 
     { a: string; skip: number; limit: number; somethingElse: number[]; }
   >}(...) */
```

Here `T` is inferred as `string`, and `EV` is inferred as `{a: string}`.  So far, so good.  But `V` is inferred as `{ a: string; skip: number; limit: number; somethingElse: number[]; }` because the `fetchMore()` method expects this type as its `variables` input.  And since the type of `V` is a subtype of `EV & PaginationVariables`, the call is completely valid.

But that means, inside the implementation of `fn()`, a call like

```
fetchMore({ skip, limit, ...extraVariables })
```

is *unsafe*. In this case it'll end up calling the `fetchMore` method with only `skip`, `limit`, and `a`, and not `somethingElse`.  And so at runtime `variables.somethingElse` will be `undefined` and not `number[]`, and `undefined` has no `map()` method.  Oops, that's a runtime error!

```
//  TypeError: variables.somethingElse is undefined
```

---

That's a problem.  You do not want the `fetchMore` method to accept some arbitrary subtype of `EV & PaginationVariables` selected by the caller.  You want it to accept *only* `EV & PaginationVariables` exactly.  That is, you don't want anything to be generic in `V` at all.  If you replace `V` with `EV & PaginationVariables`, everything starts to work the way you want it to:

```
type Props<T, EV> = {
    extraVariables: EV;
    fetchMore: (variables: EV & PaginationVariables) => Promise<T[]>;
}

function fn<T, EV>({ extraVariables, fetchMore }: Props<T, EV>) {
    const skip = 0;
    const limit = 20
    const handleClick = () => {
        fetchMore({ skip, limit, ...extraVariables }).then(() => { }) // okay
    }
}
```

And the formerly acceptable call to `fn()` is now unacceptable, because the `fecthMore()` method expects it input to have more properties than `fn()` is going to call it with:

```
fn({
    extraVariables: { a: "hello" },
    fetchMore(variables: { // error!
/*  ~~~~~~~~~ <-- Property 'somethingElse' is missing in 
      type '{ a: string; } & PaginationVariables */
        a: string, skip: number, limit: number, somethingElse: number[]
    }) { 
        return Promise.resolve(variables.somethingElse.map(x => String(x)));
    }
});
```

[Playground link to code](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?ssl=23&ssc=40&pln=22&pc=9#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-2EYfOFdWniQtcIUQuqCbqB+neB-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)